# No appear Hist in R

Tags: r, histogram

```
library(downloader)
url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/genomicsclass/dagdata/master/inst/extdata/femaleControlsPopulation.csv"
filename <- "femaleControlsPopulation"
download(url, destfile=filename)
dat <- read.csv(filename)
x <- unlist( read.csv(filename))
set.seed(1)
n <- 10000
averages5 <- vector("numeric", n)
for (i in 1:n){
x <- sample(x,5)
averages5[i] <- mean(x)
}
hist(averages5)
mean(abs(averages5-mean(x))>1)
```

I have the problem that appear empty hist and the mean is 0.....pls i need help

Comment: `dat <- read.table(file=url, header=TRUE); x <- dat$Bodyweight` Later you are overwriting `x` per (`x <- sample(x,5)`) !!!

Comment: Better do `n <- 10000; averages5 <- replicate(n, mean(sample(x,5))); hist(averages5)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer But because i m very new in this,,,,,where exactly i have to insert this code....in wich line i mean. i try to insert after the already existed dat and continue to dont appear nothing....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```
url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/genomicsclass/dagdata/master/inst/extdata/femaleControlsPopulation.csv"
dat <- read.table(file=url, header=TRUE)
x <- dat$Bodyweight
n <- 10000
averages5 <- replicate(n, mean(sample(x,5)))
hist(averages5)
```